# Get the JSON Object Node Count in Angular 2/4/5/7

Tags: angular

I am getting stuck with getting the count of the JSON Object having particular value for the parameter Name like My JSON is

So I want to total count of deployed and failed process, Also show them into font end.

```
 [{
      "id": "102",
      "username":"User 1",
      "desc": "Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s",
      "timeDeployed":"27-MAR-2019 20:21",
      "status": "Deployed"
    },
    {
        "id": "103",
        "username":"User 3",
        "desc": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry",
        "timeDeployed":"10-MAR-2019 20:21",
        "status": "Failed"
      },
      {
        "id": "104",
        "username":"User 2",
        "desc":"The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters",
        "timeDeployed":"28-DEC-2019 01:21",
        "status": "Deployed"
      },
      {
        "id": "108",
        "username":"User 1",
        "desc":"There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form",
        "timeDeployed":"10-JAN-2019 20:21",
        "status": "Deployed"
      }]
```

Comment: Can you share the code of what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@xyz was faster by a few seconds. So expanding on his answer, here's an Angular component that also shows how to include that into the front end:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:`<ul>

      <li>Deployed items: {{ deployInfo.deployed }} </li>
      <li>Failed items: {{ deployInfo.failed }} </li>



  </ul>`

})
export class AppComponent  {

   json = [{ "id": "102", "username":"User 1", "desc": "Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s", "timeDeployed":"27-MAR-2019 20:21", "status": "Deployed" }, { "id": "103", "username":"User 3", "desc": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry", "timeDeployed":"10-MAR-2019 20:21", "status": "Failed" }, { "id": "104", "username":"User 2", "desc":"The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters", "timeDeployed":"28-DEC-2019 01:21", "status": "Deployed" }, { "id": "108", "username":"User 1", "desc":"There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form", "timeDeployed":"10-JAN-2019 20:21", "status": "Deployed" }];

  deployInfo: {[status: string]: number}

  constructor() {

     this.deployInfo = this.json.reduce((acc, cur) => {
                                if (cur.status === 'Deployed') {
                                  acc.deployed ++
                                } else {
                                  acc.failed ++
                                }
                                return acc
                              }, {deployed: 0, failed: 0} );
  }


}
```

Comment: Working perfectly...Thanks Thomi

Answer (score 2):

You can use Array [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get the count in a loop

```js
var rawData = [{ "id": "102", "username":"User 1", "desc": "Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s", "timeDeployed":"27-MAR-2019 20:21", "status": "Deployed" }, { "id": "103", "username":"User 3", "desc": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry", "timeDeployed":"10-MAR-2019 20:21", "status": "Failed" }, { "id": "104", "username":"User 2", "desc":"The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters", "timeDeployed":"28-DEC-2019 01:21", "status": "Deployed" }, { "id": "108", "username":"User 1", "desc":"There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form", "timeDeployed":"10-JAN-2019 20:21", "status": "Deployed" }]

var count = rawData.reduce((acc,eachData) => {
  if (eachData.status === 'Deployed') {
    acc.deployed ++
  } else {
    acc.failed ++
  }
  return acc
}, {deployed: 0, failed: 0})

console.log(count)
```